# how two interface use two method

Tags: java, interface

If the two interfaces have same method name but different parameter, which one is invoked? if not invoked, why?

```
interface a {
    void show(int i);
}

interface b {
    void show();
}

class InterfaceTest implements b, a {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("this is show");
    }

    public void show(int a) {
        System.out.println("this is show1");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InterfaceTest it = new InterfaceTest(); 
        it.show();
        it.show(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "which one is invoked?"  You can figure out which one gets invoked by looking at the arguments passed to the method when it was called.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the method defines which one will be invoked.

The signature of your 2 show methods are different. The first does not take any argument, the second takes an int argument.

As the argument is to be provided when invoking the method, the method to invoke has been defined.